# Ionic 3 missing ionic starter folder in platforms folder

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Tried to run `ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0` latest ionic version and do not why but the `platforms\android\src\io\ionic\starter` folder is missing where **MainActivity.java** is located

Tried reinstalling a new ionic version but still misses. I am installing specific 6.3.0 android version which was working perfectly fine in my previous build, so not sure why its missing the starter folder

**Ionic info details below**

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.11.3
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Oreo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1):

Main Activity java can be found in below location

```
.. \platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\...
```

Why do you need this file? If you are building an app, APK can be found in below path

```
platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release
```